# What types of Visualforce pages cannot be used with Publisher Actions?

Tags: publisher, action

I created a VF page using code from Salesforce help files: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_access_data.htm

It uses the Account standard controller and so should appear in the list according to this document: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_vf_pages_for_custom_actions.htm&language=en_US

But when I go to Customize>Account>>Buttons Links and Actions
then
Select New Action with action type of Custom Visualforce Page it is not an option.

None of my VF pages using standard set controller extensions shows up as an option, but I cannot find any documentation that says they cannot be used as Publisher Actions on the record detail page.

Has anyone seen such a doc?  Or can anyone make the VF page described above work as a record detail Publisher Action?

Comment: Just checking...are you certain you made the VF page available for mobile? I wouldn't be surprised if this is the case. VF pages using StandardSetController aren't normally used for other single-record features, like custom buttons.

Comment: Is this a custom coded page? If so, please post your code. Publisher Actions become an option for "standard pages" once the feature has been enabled in your org.

Comment: I have no problem with my regular pages that have standard controller + extension(s). But I don't see any pages that include "recordsetvar" (= use StandardSetController). And I'm able to expose pages that aren't marked as mobile-friendly.

Comment: @peter it is checked for mobile.

Comment: @crmprogdev the code is exactly what you see in the help file linked in the original question.

Comment: @eyescream thanks for confirming that it works the same in your org.  Makes me think I will be stuck with a custom link on the record detail page, my least favorite option.

Comment: You can try taking a standard page that has the code embedded in it then extracting what you need from it using EasyPage to see if it will give you the Publisher Action code you need to add to your page. EasyPage is a free util available from the App EXchange.

Comment: I have made some progress by removing recordsetvar and adding a controller extension.  Now I can display a list, like the sample code, but I haven't managed to successfully pull the current record data.  Premier Support has been a big help!